# async data from ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I recently asked a question about working with asynchronous data.
I managed to get data from the server.

but it is not possible to update the data on the page...

when calling the getBook() function (app.component.ts), output:

```
Store {actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: ƒ} '___'
```

app.component.html:

```
  <app-layout></app-layout>
<button (click)="getBook()">get data</button>
```

effect.ts:

```
    export class AppEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private service: StoreService) {}

    update$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(

      ofType(GET_DATA),
      exhaustMap(() => 
        this.service.DataLoad()
        .pipe(
            map(
              data => DATA_LOAD(data)
              ),
        )
      )

    ), {dispatch: false});

}
```

app.component.ts:

```
      book$: Observable<any> = this.store.select((state:any) => state);

  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.store.dispatch(GET_DATA());

  }

  getBook() {

    console.log(this.book$, '___')

  }
```

reducer.ts:

```
export const initialState: any = {
  data: {}
};

export const BookReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(DATA_LOAD, (state, book) => book.results),
  on(GET_DATA, state => state)
);
```

action.ts:

```
export const DATA_KEY = 'DATA';

export const DATA_LOAD = createAction('[DATA] DATA_LOAD',  (book:any) => book);

export const GET_DATA = createAction('[DATA] GET_DATA');

export const featureSelector = createFeatureSelector<any>(DATA_KEY);
```

Comment: Can you share the `html` too?

Comment: added but is unlikely to help, so just 2 lines

Comment: Please help me. I still can't figure out what my problem is... (

Comment: I don’t see a subscription to book$?

Comment: I do not really understand

Comment: This.book$.subscribe( book => console.log(book))? Or in your html: {{ book$ | async }}

Comment: yes, with a subscription it starts to give an answer. but there is a new problem. 
the state is returned which was initialized at the beginning...

Comment: yes, I forgot about the most important thing, the subscription

Comment: still can't update state

Comment: Try to remove {dispatch: false} and try again, it needs to dispatch new action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `{dispatch: false}` config of the effect.
This makes it so the load action isn't dispatched, and thus the reducer never receives the action to update the state.